# Extraction of object from image

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, object-detection

I have used `inRange` function to remove all components apart from the two objects in the image. Is there any way I can extract the objects individually from the image? I tried using `HoughCircle` but got pretty inconsistent results.

Without inRange function(Original Image)

With HoughCircle
[image: With HoughCircle]

Comment: The image that you have shared seems to be the result after the application of the `inRange` function. Can you please share the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::findContours` seems like a good fit here:

```py
img = cv.imread('images/suawk.png')

search = cv.dilate(img, cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (5,5)))
search = cv.cvtColor(search, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, _ = cv.findContours(search, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bboxes = [cv.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, sum(rect[2]*rect[3] > 250 for rect in bboxes))
fig.set_size_inches([12,3])
fig.tight_layout()
figi = 0
for i in range(len(contours)):
    rect = cv.boundingRect(contours[i])
    area = rect[2] * rect[3]
    if area < 250:
        continue

    obj = img[rect[1]:rect[1]+rect[3]+1, rect[0]:rect[0]+rect[2]+1, :]
    obj = cv.cvtColor(obj, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    axes[figi].imshow(obj)
    figi += 1

fig.show()
```

[image: objects]

I do one dilation before findContours, so that I get less fragmented contours. I throw away all contours whose bounding box is smaller than 250px in area to reduce noise.

Comment: Extracting is easy: you have the bounds of each object in `rect` - then you just crop that part of the larger image.

Comment: Each instance of Rect contains 4 numbers right? What are those 4? Like are they the points of top and bottom?

Comment: Yes, see the documentation of cv.boundingRect

Comment: Is there also a way to set it such that subplots needs to be of a minimum size of 100 or something?

Comment: Yes you can filter the rects by their dimensions. In the example I filter only by area, but you can extend that.